# Gmaps API get latlng missing from event response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm using Angular UI Google Maps and am trying to get the latlng from where the map is clicked. Currently the map is returning a response, but without latlng. Please see my code below:

Controller

```
$scope.map = {
  center: {
    latitude: 45, longitude: -73
  },
  zoom: 8,
  events: {
    "click": function (event) {
      console.log(event.latlng);
    }
  }
};
```

html

```
  <ui-gmap-google-map events="map.events" center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

response from click:

```
Ln {gm_bindings_: Object, __gm: Wh, gm_accessors_: Object, mapTypeId: "roadmap", center: df…}__e3_: Object__gm: Whbounds: undefinedcenter: dfcontrols: Array[14]data: ghfeatures: UgetOptions: function () {gm_accessors_: Objectgm_bindings_: ObjectmapDataProviders: "Map data ©2014 Google"mapTypeId: "roadmap"mapTypes: DgmapUrl: "http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=45,-73&z=8&t=m&hl=en-US&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3"overlayMapTypes: lgstreetView: Uhtilt: 0tosUrl: "http://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html"uiGmap_id: "4b1e4213-59cd-4016-baac-2aa2af44fe1a"zoom: 8__proto__: c
```

If you need any more code please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the event will return it as an array from a third argument, please see fix below. I hope this helps someone :)

```
$scope.map = {
  center: {
    latitude: 45, longitude: -73
  },
  zoom: 8,
  events: {
    "click": function (event, a, b) {
      console.log(a);
      console.log(b);

    }
  }
};
```